# How to work with mysql in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

my visual studio 2008 don't know "MySql.Data.MySqlClient" and says:
"The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need **Connector/Net**

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.2.html

> Connector/Net is a fully-managed ADO.NET driver for MySQL.

Here're some guides

http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=576

http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article68.aspx

[How do I set up MySQL to work with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359880/how-do-i-set-up-mysql-to-work-with-c)

Answer (score 6):

You should add a reference to "MySql.Data.dll" in your Visual Studio 2008 project via rightclick/add reference.

The MySql.Data.dll should be part of the [.Net MySql connector which is available here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).
And there is [a kind of tutorial for MySQL and C#](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/dotnet/) too.

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Framework Data Providers (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx)

[Connecting to MySQL database from your .NET applications.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ConnectMySQL.aspx)

[Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) AND [How to connect to MySQL  5.0. via C# .Net and the MySql Connector/Net](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html)

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem download MySql.Data.dll from

https://www.cryptool.org/trac/CrypTool2/export/2020/trunk/AppReferences/x64/MySql.Data.dll

Then right click on your project name, click on add reference and select MySql.Data.dll file